# Safe to use this?

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, xcode, rss

I'm not that good in understanding apple documentation, but is it "Safe" to use this: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-building-advanced-rss-reader/
In a Xcode project, or will apple reject the app because it is customized?

I understand this might be a stupid question, but since Im not sure of the rules, I thought I ask first.

Also, what is the best way to release it?

Thank you in advance!

All the best,

Andy

Comment: Andy, if you have any questions on this article you can always leave a comment in Touch Code Magazine or directly write me an email to: touch-code-magazine ( a t ) underplot (d o t) com

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely safe to use.  I use GData in my project and Apple never rejected it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I read in the commentfield of the article that there was some issues regarding 'realeasing'...

Comment: @Andy: Just looked at the comment; that's not something you need to worry about.  Releasing is a term for getting rid of memory you don't need, and the commenter was concerned why he was having the system manage it (`autorelease`) instead of releasing it himself (`release`).  That doesn't mean that the code is unsafe to use. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use without any problem. And you can also use NSXLMParser.